# Regex Python capture string in quotes

Tags: python, regex, io, pattern-matching

I have a file with lines of this form:

`ClientsName(0) = "SUPERBRAND": ClientsName(1) = "GREATSTUFF": cClientsNames.Add Key:="SUPER", Item:=ClientsName`

and I would like to capture the names in quotes `""` after `ClientsName(0) =` and `ClientsName(1) =`.

So far, I came up with this code

```
import re

f = open('corrected_clients_data.txt', 'r')
result = ''
re_name = "ClientsName\(0\) = (.*)"
for line in f:
    name = re.search(line, re_name)
    print (name)
```

which is returning `None` at each line...

Two sources of error can be: the backslashes and the capture sequence `(.*)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that more easily using `re.findall` and using `\d` instead of `0` to make it more general:

```
import re

s = '''ClientsName(0) = "SUPERBRAND": ClientsName(1) = "GREATSTUFF": cClientsNames.Add Key:="SUPER", Item:=ClientsName'''

>>> print re.findall(r'ClientsName\(\d\) = "([^"]*)"', s)
['SUPERBRAND', 'GREATSTUFF']
```

Another thing you must note is that your order of arguments to `search()` or `findall()` is wrong. It should be as follows: `re.search(pattern, string)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookbehind to get the value of `ClientsName(0)` and `ClientsName(1)` through `re.findall` function,

```
>>> import re
>>> str = '''ClientsName(0) = "SUPERBRAND": ClientsName(1) = "GREATSTUFF": cClientsNames.Add Key:="SUPER", Item:=ClientsName'''
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?<=ClientsName\(0\) = \")[^"]*|(?<=ClientsName\(1\) = \")[^"]*', str)
>>> m
['SUPERBRAND', 'GREATSTUFF']
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=ClientsName\(0\) = \")` Positive lookbehind is used to set the matching marker just after to the string `ClientsName(0) = "`
- `[^"]*` Then it matches any character not of `"` zero or more times. So it match the first value ie, `SUPERBRAND`
- `|` Logical OR operator used to combine two regexes.
- `(?<=ClientsName\(1\) = \")[^"]*` Matches any character just after to the string  `ClientsName(1) = "` upto the next `"`. Now it matches the second value ie, `GREATSTUFF`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` and just take the first two matches:

```
>>> s = '''ClientsName(0) = "SUPERBRAND": ClientsName(1) = "GREATSTUFF": cClientsNames.Add Key:="SUPER", Item:=ClientsName'''
>>> re.findall(r'\"([^"]+)\"' , s)[:2]
['SUPERBRAND', 'GREATSTUFF']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import re

text_file = open("corrected_clients_data.txt", "r")
text = text_file.read()
matches=re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"',text)

text_file.close()
```

if you notice the question mark(?) indicates that we have to stop reading the string
at the first ending double quotes encountered.

hope this is helpful.